# How to retrieve the data out of a Silverlight DataContext Object

Tags: c#, silverlight, datacontext

I have a Silverlight application which is a collection of form fields and buttons.

I've created a method stub that handles a click event in the xaml.cs. When I inspect sender during debug, I can see the base type is a TextBlock, and in the DataContext object within that textblock I see my custom type's properties. One of them is GUID - this is the Sender's type, so I cast to a TextBlock and I can see the DataContext, but I am not sure how to get my type's field value out of this object:

```
private void someTextField_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        var dataContext = (TextBlock) sender;
        var assetGUID = dataContext.DataContext.  /
        // intellsense does not show any fields, indexers, or getters - Just says "Get or Set datacontext fields in a datacontext".

    }
```

As stated, if I debug and place a watch on Sender, go two levels deep I can see my objects fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can see in Debug mode, that the DataContext of the TextBlock is your needed Object, then you just have to cast it to your object.

```
private void someTextField_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        var dataContext = (TextBlock) sender;
        var assetGUID = ((YourObject)dataContext.DataContext).getGuid()  /
        // intellsense does not show any fields, indexers, or getters - Just says "Get or Set datacontext fields in a datacontext".

    }
```

You need to do this, because DataContext is defined with the return value Object ([DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

Is this what you need?

BR,

TJ